# Terminal printing carriage return as ^M?? [linux telling me to stop coding?]

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, cursor, carriage-return

I was writing a script in vim, dropped my keyboard, and continued coding.

I didn't notice that my cursor changed from the normal _ type cursor, to a [] block. (as if i hit insert in a windows terminal)
I started up my script, and got a /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter error.

With plenty of googling, ^M is the dos carriage return.. but when I hit enter in terminal it looks like a normal carriage return. But bash interprets it as ^M.  

I practically keyboard slammed to see what on earth I hit to change this. can someone help me out here?

Comment: No, it's just telling you to move to Windows.

Comment: it doesn't count that its a guest in windows 7? =P

Comment: Are you sure that an "Enter" in your VM inserts a CRLF? You can test it with: `cat > testcrlf && hexdump testcrlf`. When this line is executed in the terminal, press Enter followed by Ctrl + D. You should see just `0a` in the right column, not `0a0d`.

Comment: see this same behaviour on macbook air. http://xkcd.com/979/

Answer (score 3):

When you dropped your keyboard, not only did it hit the <kbd>Insert</kbd> key, but it managed to enter the `:set tx` command as well.  Run the `:set fileformat=unix` command in the edit buffer for the file concerned, and then re-save the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a file with CRLF line terminators to LF, run:

```
sed 's/\r$//' -i your-script-filename
```

If it's an issue in vim (and not your terminal), look at [gVim showing carriage return (^M) even when file mode is explicitly DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/799417/427545)

Comment: Not an answer. He wants to stop writing CRLF when pressing Return on Linux.